# permutations of splitting string into n substrings in Python

Tags: python, runtime, permutation

I have a string of each letter that I'd like to split into all possible combinations but with a given number of substrings, so that:

```
a = 'abcdefghi...'
```

splits into 4 substrings:

```
comb = [['abcdefghi...'], [''], [''], ['']],[['bcdefghi...'], ['a'], [''], ['']],[['cdefghi...'], ['ab'], [''], ['']]....[[''], [''], [''], ['abcdefghi...']]
```

My biggest problem rn is the time consumption to do this for the whole alphabet.

Any Ideas?

Comment: You can't really do better than 26^4 iterations..
But dependant on what you want to do with it you can think about lazy calculations.

Answer (score 0):

```
def per_string(s,n, out_list=[], lst=[]):
    if s == "":
        out_list.append(lst[::-1])
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if len(lst)<n:
            lst.append([s[i:]])
            per_string(s[:i], n,out_list, lst)
            lst.pop()
    return out_list
```